# Npgsql connection not releasing

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, database-connection, npgsql, connection-leaks

I have a client app using Entity Framework Core 5 with Npgsql to access PostgreSQL. The client app may make multiple connections to the database.

The problem is, after we killed the client app and shutdown the client machine, we can still see the connections from pgAdmin dashboard on the server.

We should not see these connection in pgAdmin as the client app is totally shutdown, does anyone know what is happening?

Is it because we kill the client app during a transaction or during a query wait?

If we inspect the connection query then we can see that it is performing a select statement. We suspect that it is waiting for another transaction to complete before returning the data but the client was killed and it didn't know about that. Would this be a right assumption?

Comment: If you literally kill a process then the other end of the TCP connection may not know about it until there’s an attempt to use that connection. If there’s a longer query in progress that may not be canceled since the server may assume the connection is still open.

Comment: I would have thought that Npgsql would detect SIGTERM then gracefully remove all connections from connection pool and disconnect. From an aspnet core perspective, it is not practicle to find all instances of DbContext to close connection.

Comment: The issue tracking this in Npgsql is https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1606.